# How do I copy data from one column in table A to table B in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, table A and table B. Table A has a list of item names, and their unique IDs. Table B has a list of those same item names, but not the IDs. I want to copy the IDs over to table B based on the item name. I've already created the column in a separate command in table B, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to copy this over. I used the following code:

```
Update B
Set B.ID = 
(Select A.ID From A Where A.Name = B.Name)
Where Exists (Select A.ID From A Where A.Name = B.Name);
```

But I keep getting errors with it. Specifically:
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

ID is Alphanumeric. Names and IDs are not necessarily unique, so if a name value recurs I want it to still assign the correct ID.

Help?

Comment: Update B Set B.ID = (Select max(A.ID) From A Where A.Name=B.Name)

Comment: You have at least two rows in A with the same Name. So, what do you want to store in table B in this scenario? Both IDs? One of them, and if so, which one?

Comment: ID is Alphanumeric. And yes, I want to copy the ID to both. Names and IDs are not necessarily unique, so if a name value recurs I want it to still assign the correct ID.

Comment: If a name value recurs (presumably with different ID's) **which** is the "correct" ID to copy to the other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define what the "correct" id is.  You can easily get *one* id, using either `rownum` or an aggregation function:

```
Update B
    Set B.ID = (Select A.ID From A Where A.Name = B.Name and rownum = 1)
    Where Exists (Select A.ID From A Where A.Name = B.Name);
```

or:

```
Update B
    Set B.ID = (Select max(A.ID) From A Where A.Name = B.Name)
    Where Exists (Select A.ID From A Where A.Name = B.Name);
```

One of these should address your problem.

Although I would not recommend it, you could also get a list of all matching ids:

```
Update B
    Set B.ID = (Select listagg(A.ID, ',') within group (order by A.ID) From A Where A.Name = B.Name)
    Where Exists (Select A.ID From A Where A.Name = B.Name);
```

I do abhor storing lists as comma-delimited strings, however.

Comment: "I do abhor storing lists..." You are in good company, so does First Normal Form.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use for loop, see below code.

```
BEGIN
    FOR tab_a IN (SELECT ID, NAME
                    FROM table_a)
    LOOP
         UPDATE table_b
            SET id = tab_a.id
          WHERE name = tab_a.name;
         --comment dbms_output if a lot of records involved or you can increase the output size
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab_a.name||':::'||SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    END LOOP;
END;
/

COMMIT;
```

Comment: That might be way slower than SQL option. Besides, it "solves" the TOO-MANY-ROWS in a mysterious way as you have no idea which ID will be assigned to which name. The last one you fetch, of course, but - which one is it? There's no ORDER BY clause in cursor loop's SELECT statement. I think I don't like such a solution very much.

Comment: putting an ORDER BY is a great idea, but I believe is not necessary since table_a contains unique records (names and ids, if my assumption is right) and one or more records in table_b could contain similar names, UPDATE statement above could updates one or more records that is why i put some line to output the number of records updated, if below update will be used in the application i would agree to you that "that might be the slower option" but I think solution to this problem will not be used always, maybe one time only so performance would not be an issue

Comment: also, i don't understand why you mentioned TOO_MANY_ROWS as there is no SELECT INTO clause in the code above, it is only an update

Comment: I think that your assumption is wrong - there **are** duplicate names, that's why OP's query returned TOO-MANY-ROWS (OP's, not yours). Furthermore, that's why your solution sets the same ID (the last selected in cursor FOR loop for that *name*) for all of those *duplicates*, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: ah, ok, if that is so, then you could be right, thanks